# iOS app that shows a list of values to toggle on/off

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app that contains a customizable list of fields, with a binary on/off or yes/no switch on each.

This is seemingly impossible to search for, given the generic words involved.

The usage is: I carry three laptop battery bricks with unique serial numbers. As one depletes, I insert the next one. They all look identical except for the serial number, so it's helpful to make a note of which one is spent or not. I'd like a simple app where I can list the three, e.g.,

1. EZXXXXX
2. TYXXXXX
3. FLXXXXX

With on/off switches next to them, so I can toggle and see at a glance which is spent. Often I wind up having only one with juice on it, and I have to cycle through all three and power the laptop on before finding the right one.

Answer (score 1):

[AFewThings](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/shinpurunato-do-afewthings/id424417385?mt=8) on the JP app store. Excellent primitive (non-flat) interface, no ads, and you just add/delete a line and pulse it to turn strikethrough on or off. Finally, an app that does one thing and one thing only! And it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any shopping list app could do that - I use [AnyList](https://www.anylistapp.com), iOS & OS X versions, sync across devices, share with named parties.

Items "bought" can be hidden when "purchased" or just crossed [struck] through - so that might just be the single function from it that you need, tap to toggle state from crossed to clear.

You might even find it handy for *actual* shopping lists, which movies you want to see, music you need to check out, what to take on holiday... etc etc ;)

I *think* the basic version is free - but I bought the full version some time ago so it's hard to tell.

Comment: You got me in the right direction. That was vaguely in the back of my mind, but I had the feeling that a traditional to-do list would involve checkboxes, a bunch of extraneous features, etc. AnyList lets you push the whole line anywhere to toggle on/off. I wound up finding [AFewThings](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/shinpurunato-do-afewthings/id424417385?mt=8), which is gloriously ad-free and has no features but pulsing the line on or off. Not sure if that is available in every region's App Store.

Comment: Any shopping/to-do list type app is going to have some amount of *extraneous*, for sure - I just thought the simple 'plain text vs crossed out' might satisfy that one need - you can always ignore the rest... like I've never used the 'recipe' function, nor never will ;)

Comment: I've revealed my true colors. I am an extreme Unix command line minimalist at heart, so I bristle at extraneous cruft. I've never liked ignoring things that vie for attention if I can obscure them entirely. I don't want my toaster to have a pancake defrost feature, either :D

Comment: I'm sure my toaster has a 'croissant feature'... but as I've never even tested it I neither know nor care - not that I'm in any way insisting *my recommendation is the be-all & end-all* but the cruft you only see at the welcome screen after an update - rest of the time it's invisible ;)